# "ValueError: '' is not in list" is given as an error instead of just moving on in an elif statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if-statement

So I'm currently writing a simple script in Python that should handle a ROT13 cipher. I wrote this small chunk of code that should theoretically check if the given letter is uppercase, lowercase, or not in the alphabet such as punctuation. However, if I feed it a character such as a space or an exclamation point that isn't in the alphabet it will throw me a Value error and say that it's not in the list referenced in my elif statement instead of just running the else statement. What can I do so that if the character is not in the alphabet list it won't break the program? Thanks.

For reference plain_alphabet and cipher_alphabet are just lists that contain every letter of the alphabet. I know it's inefficient but it works so far.

message is also just a string.

```
for x in message:
    if x in plain_alphabet:
        message_list.append(cipher_alphabet[plain_alphabet.index(x)])
    elif x in [x.upper() for y in plain_alphabet]:
        message_list.append((cipher_alphabet[plain_alphabet.index(x.lower())]).upper())
    else:
        message_list.append(x)
print(''.join(message_list))
```

Comment: Without trying to understand the code too deeply, I think you meant to write `elif x in [y.upper() for y in plain_alphabet]:`

Comment: I think the problem is what happens when the if/elif/else condition is met and you are trying to append, not that the conditioning is working incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

user10987432 was right, `elif x in [x.upper() for y in plain_alphabet]:` should've been `elif x in [**y**.upper() for y in plain_alphabet]:`